# Efficiently Check for Existence in a Grouped Set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to group over one column checking over some boolean expression in another.

For instance, Say I have a single table:

**MyTable**

```
ID  | ColA
----------
1     A
1     B
1     C
2     A
2     C
```

What I would like to do is fetch all records over some boolean selection logic. For instance fetch all IDs where a `ColA` exists with values `A` and `B`

Something similar to

```
SELECT ID, ColA
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = 'A')
AND ID IN (SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = 'B')
```

To Return the selection

```
ID | ColA
---------
1    A
1    B
1    C
```

Something like the above would work, but it doesn't seem to be all too efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write the query using `exists` and then be sure that some indexes are defined:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.ColA
FROM MyTable t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.ColA = 'A') AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t.ID AND t2.ColA = 'B') ;
```

The index that you want is `MyTable(id, ColA)`.

Answer (score 0):

The query you propose is not too bad for the problem you present.  No, it doesn't look so efficient, but what you're asking to do cannot be performed very efficiently.

This variation is at least a little *clearer*, and perhaps SQL Server's query planner could do something useful with it:

```
SELECT ID, ColA
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = 'A'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT ID FROM MyTable WHERE ColA = 'B'
)
```

Comment: This works for the case of `and` as the example shows but would be hard to chain with an `or` clause as well. It is cleaner though :)